# C - Read/write int variable in .txt

Tags: c

I'm starting to learn C, and currently programming a little text-based lottery-like game. But I need a way to store the value in the end of the game, so it can be kept for the next plays. I made a simpler code below that represents what I need. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //TODO get "int saved" from save.txt
    printf("Value saved: %d\n", saved);
    printf("Add: ");
    int add;
    scanf("%d", &add);
    int new = saved+add;
    printf("New value: %d\n", new);
    //TODO save "int new" to save.txt
}
```

save.txt:

```
100
```

Comment: Google is what you need at the moment. Try that figure a bit of it yourself if problem still persist come here with a specific problem, Don't ask for whole solution here...

Comment: @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ Yes, problem does persist. All solutions I found were about arrays and/or multiple data in a file. And if I was actually asking for the whole solution, I'd have just slapped my whole code here and asked for a full fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
FILE *file;
int   saved;
int   add;

file = fopen("saved.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "error opening `saved.txt'\n");
    return -1;
 }

if (fscanf(file, "%d", &saved) != 1)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "file `saved.txt' corrupted\n");
    fclose(file);
    return -1;
 }

fprintf(stdout, "please input an integer > ");
if (scanf("%d", &add) != 1)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
    fclose(file);
    return -1;
 }
fclose(file);

file = fopen("saved.txt", "w");
if (file != NULL)
 {
    fprintf(file, "%d\n", saved + add);
    fclose(file);
 }
```

Comment: I guess that covers the .txt to int part. How do I save int new back to the .txt, replacing the first value?

Comment: @UToast if there will always be 1 value in the file, the above code works.